# WordPress 3 level jQuery mobile menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I need some help with the following menu JS script: http://cdpn.io/LzuJh

At the moment the script works but I need some proper cleaning. I am able to get it to expand on click to about the second level and everything goes haywire from then onward.

I want it to behave like a proper 3 level menu. 
1) you click on menu icon it opens the menu
2) you click on the second menu it opens the menu and gives you access to 3rd menu etc

NB: I also want the menu to toggle, the same way it toggles on the top menu. any help will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the rest of the tutorial from my website: http://bit.ly/1m6nnVq

I have a big head, but not on Stackoverflow. Feel free to drop me an email whenever you need any form of assistance.

```
/*-------------------------------------
 * Responsive / Mobi Menu
 *-----------------------------------*/
 var pull = jQuery('.menu-ico i.fa');   // define trigger / activator

 jQuery(pull).click(function(){
    jQuery('.menu-top-menu-container ul#top-menu').slideToggle();
    return false;
 });

 jQuery('.menu-top-menu-container ul#top-menu li').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).find('ul').length > 0)
    {
        jQuery(this).addClass('menu');
    }
 });

 jQuery('.menu-top-menu-container ul#top-menu').hide();

 jQuery('.menu-top-menu-container .menu > a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().find('ul:first').slideToggle();
    return false;
 });
```